# How to run consecutive executions after execution times out?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spotify, execution

I'm running a script on my personal Google account using Spotify API. I'm limited to six minutes for each execution run time. I need the execution to run longer than that for me to retrieve all the episodes for my list of podcasts.

Is there a way for me to automatically run the execution again once I reach the six-minute time-out and pick up where the previous execution had left off? I don't want to manually edit the GSheets range in the script where I read in the list of podcasts for every execution. I would also like the `clear()` code in my script to only run in the first round of execution - I don't want to clear all of the episodes from the first run when the consecutive executions follow.

```
function getEpisodes() {

  var clientId = <your Spotify API client ID>;
  var clientSecret = <your Spotify API client secret>; 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<sheet ID>);
  var sListOfPodcasts = ss.getSheetByName("List of podcasts");
  var sOutput = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  var arrPodcasts = sListOfPodcasts.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  sOutput.getRange("A2:L").clear();

  var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
  var params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(clientId + ":" + clientSecret)},
    payload: {grant_type: "client_credentials"},
  };

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var token = obj.access_token;

  Logger.log("token = " + token);

  var parameters = {       
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
          },
        json : true,
  };

  for (const show of arrPodcasts) {

    let offset = 0;
    let j = 1; // this is later used to index the episodes per podcast in the logs

    var getPodcast = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/episodes";
    var fetchPodcast = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getPodcast, parameters);
    var totEps = JSON.parse(fetchPodcast.getContentText()).total
    Logger.log("total episodes = " + totEps);

    let n = Math.floor(totEps/50) + 1; // determine number of loops needed to retrieve all episodes
    Logger.log("We need to loop " + n + " times");   

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {

      var podcasts = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/episodes?offset=" + offset + "&limit=50&market=GB";
      Logger.log(podcasts);

      Logger.log("Offset = " + offset);
      
      var nameShow = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/?market=gb", parameters).getContentText()).name;
      var publisher = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/?market=gb", parameters).getContentText()).publisher;
      Logger.log(nameShow);

      try {
        var podcast = UrlFetchApp.fetch(podcasts, parameters);
      }
      catch(err) {
        Logger.log("Move onto the next podcast");
      }
      
      var object = JSON.parse(podcast.getContentText()); 
      
      offset = (c+1) * 50;
      Logger.log("Offset = " + offset);                     

      if (c == n) {
        break; // break the loop when we retrive the last batch of episodes, then move onto the next podcast
      }

      for (let b = 0; b < 1; b++) {  

        for (const episode of object.items) {

          Logger.log(j + ') ' + episode.name + '\n'+ episode.release_date);
          j = j + 1; // index the episodes for each podcast

          var rowStart = sOutput.getLastRow() + 1;          
          sOutput.getRange(rowStart, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[nameShow, publisher, episode.name, episode.release_date, episode.description, episode.type, episode.explicit, episode.duration_ms, "https://open.spotify.com/embed/episode/" + episode.id, episode.images[0].url]]);

        }                   

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Below is what my list of podcast episodes looks like on GSheets.

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can store your execution start up params in PropertiesService

Comment: I'm trying to use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties()` in various ways but no luck. I don't understand how to use PropertiesService in apps script.

Comment: I would store the information I  need to preserve between executions in a stringified object and just use JSON.parse whenever I pulll it out.  Make sure you update it after every execution.  You will have to quit executing your code early enough so that you don't reach the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received great help from [u/JetCarson](https://www.reddit.com/user/JetCarson/) on Reddit and got a solution.

Set up a time-based trigger for `spotify()`. Don't worry the `ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i])` part of the script will not delete the `spotify()` trigger.

```
function spotify() {
  clearProperties();
  getEpisodes();
}

// run this function first to clear the properties before reading in values from the Spotify API
function clearProperties() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('LastShowIndexRead');
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('lastEpisodeOffset');
};    

function getEpisodes() {  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<sheetID>);
  var sListOfPodcasts = ss.getSheetByName("List of podcasts");
  var sOutput = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  var arrPodcasts = sListOfPodcasts.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

  //these are needed to ensure we don't go over 360 seconds of execution time
  const MAX_TIME = 5 * 60 * 1000; // run the execution for 5 mins
  var startTime = new Date();

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == 'getEpisodes') { // make sure the name of the function in if statement is in string format
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    } 
  }
  
  //this next variable will be used to determine where we start off on this call to this function
  var lastShowIndexRead = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('LastShowIndexRead');

  // if lastShowIndexRead is NULL then lastShowIndexRead is 0, else parse lastShowIndexRead as an integer
  lastShowIndexRead = (lastShowIndexRead === null ? 0 : parseInt(lastShowIndexRead));

  // this variable is the offset value used in the UrlFetch when getting each episode for each podcast
  var lastEpisodeOffset = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastEpisodeOffset');
  lastEpisodeOffset = (lastEpisodeOffset === null ? 0 : parseInt(lastEpisodeOffset));

  //we'll now delete the property so it won't be used again on another call
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('lastShowIndexRead');
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('lastEpisodeOffset');

  if (lastEpisodeOffset === 0 && lastShowIndexRead === 0) {
    sOutput.getRange("A2:L").clear(); // only clear the spreadsheet on the first execution run of this function
    };

  let j = sOutput.getLastRow();

  var clientId = <your clientID>;
  var clientSecret = <your clientSecret>;

  var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
  var params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(clientId + ":" + clientSecret)},
    payload: {grant_type: "client_credentials"},
  };

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var token = obj.access_token;

  Logger.log("token = " + token);

  var parameters = {       
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
          },
        json : true,
  };

  for (var showIndex = lastShowIndexRead; showIndex <  arrPodcasts.length; showIndex++) {

    const show = arrPodcasts[showIndex][0];
    
    if (show !== '') {

      let offset = lastEpisodeOffset;
      lastEpisodeOffset = 0;

      var getPodcast = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/episodes";
      var fetchPodcast = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getPodcast, parameters);
      var totEps = JSON.parse(fetchPodcast.getContentText()).total;
      Logger.log("total episodes = " + totEps);

      let n = Math.floor(totEps/50) + 1; // determine number of loops needed to retrieve all episodes for the podcast
      Logger.log("We need to loop " + n + " times");
        
      var outputArray = [];

      do {

        var podcasts = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/${show}/episodes?offset=${offset}&limit=50&market=GB`;
        Logger.log(podcasts);

        Logger.log("Offset = " + offset);
        
        var obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/" + show + "/?market=gb", parameters).getContentText());

        var nameShow = obj.name;
        var publisher = obj.publisher;

        Logger.log(nameShow);

        try {
          var podcast = UrlFetchApp.fetch(podcasts, parameters);
        }
        catch(err) {
          Logger.log("Move onto the next podcast");
        }
        
        var object = JSON.parse(podcast.getContentText()); 

        Logger.log("Offset = " + offset);                     

        if ('items' in object) {

          for (var i = 0; i < object.items.length; i++) {

            offset++;
            var episode = object.items[i];

            if (episode !== null) {

              Logger.log(j + ') ' + episode.name + '\n'+ episode.release_date);
              j = j + 1; // index the episodes for each podcast

              //var rowStart = sOutput.getLastRow() + 1;          
              //sOutput.getRange(rowStart, 1, 1, 12).setValues([[nameShow, publisher, episode.name, episode.release_date, episode.description, episode.type, episode.explicit, episode.duration_ms, "https://open.spotify.com/embed/episode/" + episode.id, episode.images[0].url, showIndex, offset]]);
              outputArray.push([nameShow, publisher, episode.name, episode.release_date, episode.description, episode.type, episode.explicit, episode.duration_ms, "https://open.spotify.com/embed/episode/" + episode.id, episode.images[0].url, showIndex, offset]);

            }

          }
        } else {
          console.log(`ERROR: no items found in object`);
        }

        var currentTime = new Date();

        // if execution time exceeds define MAX_TIME and there are still more episodes to retrieve, then build a new trigger and resume in the next trigger rather than letting the current execution time out
        if (offset < totEps && currentTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime() > MAX_TIME) {

          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('LastShowIndexRead', showIndex.toString());
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastEpisodeOffset', offset.toString());
          
          ScriptApp.newTrigger('getEpisodes')
            .timeBased()
            .at(new Date(new Date().getTime() + (20 * 1000))) // 20 seconds from NOW
            .create();

          console.log(`Trigger created to resume ${'getEpisodes'} in 20 seconds...`);
          return; //exit before the time-out

        }
        
      } while (offset < totEps);

      var rowStart = sOutput.getLastRow() + 1;  
      sOutput.getRange(rowStart, 1, outputArray.length, outputArray[0].length).setValues(outputArray);

    }
  }
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful!